# Closest value (snapping)

Tags: javascript, math

if I have a range slider that uses steps, for example from 0 to 100 with a step of 5, and then I have a random value between that range, let's say 56, how can I determine what's the closest snap value (55) ?

I was thinking to loop forwards and backwards until I find the closest number divisible by 5, but there has to be a better approach ?

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times before, please use the search before posting a question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just use

```
snapped = Math.round(x / step) * step
```